# How can i subs or replace a sympy function to a sympy symbol

Tags: python-3.x, function, sympy, symbols

Im trying to replace the sympy function x(t) to the sympy symbol x.

It should be like something like this:

Before the replace:
funcion0=t**2*sp.cos((x(t)/2))

After the replace:
funcion1=t**2*sp.cos((x/2))

```
import sympy as sp
t = sp.Symbol('t')
x = sp.Function('x')
funcion=t**2*sp.cos((x(t)/2))

def replace(funcion):
   funcion1=funcion.subs(x(t), x)
   return funcion1
```

I know that doesnt work, but maybe it helps to understand what im saying hahaha.
Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with SymPy, it's best to keep in mind the differences between functions, symbols and physical numbers like floats or ints. Here, you want the function `x` (evaluated at `t`) to be substituted with the symbol `x`. If you are uncertain at any point, it is best to add what the type of the variable to its name as I have done below:

```py
import sympy as sp
t, x_sym = sp.symbols('t x')
x_func = sp.Function('x')
function = t**2*sp.cos((x_func(t)/2))

def replace(funcion):
    function1 = funcion.subs(x_func(t), x_sym)
    return function1

print(replace(function))
```

It should give you the desired result.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked!! I will keep your advice in mind for my next projects! Have a good day!!